# Find a URL inside Twig file from content made from another content type (referenced/ has a relationship)

Tags: uri

I'm new to Drupal, and have stumbled across this issue.
I have entries (entry) that are blogs held inside a blog_listing. E.g.

```
{% for entry in content.field_blog_listing_entries|field_target_entity %}
    <h2>{{ entry.title.value }}</h2>
    <p>{{ entry.field_blog_excerpt.value }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

The blogs are their own entries that have automatically generated URLs. e.g. Blog 1 can be found on blogs/blog-1.

How do I get this URL from within the code block above?

I want to access the value in the same manner that I do with the `title` and `field_blog_excerpt` to put into an anchor tag. I've tried the same method e.g. `entry.url.value` & `entry.field_blog_url.value` but these don't return anything.

How do I access this URL value?
Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use path function with the route for node (entity.node.canonical) and the entry.id (node id) for your blog entry. Pass the id in with the "node" parameter.

`<a href="{{ path('entity.node.canonical', {'node': entry.id}) }}"></a>`

More info here: https://www.drupal.org/docs/theming-drupal/twig-in-drupal/functions-in-twig-templates